# PHP 4 excel export without using OLE

Tags: php, export-to-excel

What is the best lib to make a report in Excel 97-2003 (*.xls) file format without using OLE? It have to work with PHP 4 and support styling.

Answer (score 0):

According to it's changelog, [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) works with PHP4.

Comment: oh, I supposed that php 4 does not support classes... thank you, I will try it.